# how to create android UI so that it does not change with screen resolution?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have an android app with a background image,which I would deploy on emulator and see its behavior.

Initially I was using emulator with skin WVGA800.In the UI all the textView declared in the layout were properly placed.
But when I change the emulator skin to 500x600 then in UI few of the textView are misplaced.

So could anyone please suggest how to handle this.

Comment: can u pls post ur code here??

Comment: Layout code always in demand :)

Comment: Screenshots of the "broken" and "working" layouts would be a good idea, also.

Comment: I don't really see the point of a 500x600 emulator since no Android devices have that resolution. Maybe you could mimic some actual devices and make sure your UI looks good?

Comment: Did you go through this. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html Amazing documentation.

Comment: typical usecase of multiple resoultions!

Answer (score 0):

The good, but difficult thing about Android is that you don't know what size or aspect ratio the device your code runs on will be. If you want full-screen images, you need to be willing to have them scaled (proportionally or disproportionally) or cropped.

If you're trying to position text in a particular place on a background image, you're going to have a bad time. I've tried this before and quickly changed my mind.

Here's my suggestion: Read the screens support [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) (as @abhilasha said) and use adaptive UI elements that scale nicely (like 9-patch images, relative layouts, etc).

Then if you want to place text in an image, instead of trying to place a `TextView` over an `ImageView`, set the image you want as the background of the `TextView`. Then you know where the text will be relative to the image.

Answer (score 0):

My options:
1)for simple ui,i think u can use many attars with view,the following;
android:layout_centerHrizontal 
android:layout_centerVertical
android:layout_centerInparent
android:layout_alignParentBottom 
android:layout_alignParentLeft
android:layout_alignParentRight
android:layout_alignParentTop
android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing

android:layout_below
android:layout_above
android:layout_toLeftOf
android:layout_toRightOf
android:layout_alignTop
android:layout_alignLeft
android:layout_alignBottom 
android:layout_alignRight

android:layout_marginBottom
android:layout_marginLeft
android:layout_marginRight
android:layout_marginTop

that is helpful to use layout or view attars to set its position.
2)u can use some layouts xml to fit it.like that

```
if(screen width < 480)
setcontentview(r.layout.for480lay)
else if(screen width > 480&&screen width <640)
setcontentview(r.layout.for640lay)
..
..
```